# JSX expressions must have one parent element React Native .map

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, expo

I'm trying to insert Markers and Circles on a MapView in React-Native.
When I insert these two together I receive the following error `JSX expressions must have one parent element.`

I've tried to insert only one of these, I received no errors but still nothing worked.
I'm using a map in my array of data and using my flood.id as key, although this is an a string, so I don't know if this is an issue.

I printed in the console all the variables that I'm using inside the map and they were all there.

Here is my code:

```
interface Flood {
    id: string;
    userId: string;
    latitude: number;
    longitude: number;
    type: string;
    source: string;
    description: string;
    waterLevel: string;
    startDate: string;
    finishDate: string;
    status: boolean;
    range: number;
    reports: string[];
    images: {
        path: string
    };
    hazards: {
        type: string,
        status: true,
    };
}

export default function IncidentsMap({navigation}: { navigation: any }) {
    const [location, setLocation] = useState<Location>();
    const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState<any>(null);
    const [floods, setFloods] = useState<Flood[]>([]);

    function handleNavigateToCreateIncident() {
        navigation.navigate('SelectIncidentLocation')
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            let {status} = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
            if (status !== 'granted') {
                setErrorMsg('Permission to access location was denied');
                return;
            }
            let variable = await Location.getForegroundPermissionsAsync();

            let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({accuracy: 6});
            setLocation(location);

            api.get('floods').then(response => {
                setFloods(response.data);
            })
        })();

    }, []);

    function handleNavigateToIncidentDetails() {
        navigation.navigate('IncidentDetails');
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            {typeof location?.coords.latitude == 'number' ?
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <MapView
                        provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
                        style={styles.map}
                        initialRegion={{
                            latitude: location?.coords.latitude!,
                            longitude: location?.coords.longitude!,
                            latitudeDelta: 0.008,
                            longitudeDelta: 0.008,
                        }}>
                        {floods.map(flood => {
                            // noinspection BadExpressionStatementJS
                            <Circle
                                key={flood.id}
                                center={{
                                    latitude: flood.latitude,
                                    longitude: flood.longitude
                                }}
                                radius={flood.range}
                                fillColor={'rgba(53, 159, 181,0.4)'}
                            />
                            <Marker
                                key={flood.id}
                                icon={mapMarker}
                                calloutAnchor={{
                                    x: 2.7,
                                    y: 0.8
                                }}
                                coordinate={{
                                    latitude: flood?.latitude,
                                    longitude: flood?.longitude
                                }}
                            >
                                <Callout tooltip={true} onPress={handleNavigateToIncidentDetails}>
                                    <View style={styles.calloutContainer}>
                                        <Text style={styles.calloutText}>{flood.type}</Text>
                                    </View>
                                </Callout>
                            </Marker>
                        })}

                    </MapView>
                    <View style={styles.footer}>
                        <Text style={styles.footerText}>Reporte um incidente</Text>
                        <RectButton style={styles.createFloodButton} onPress={handleNavigateToCreateIncident}>
                            <Feather name='plus' size={20} color={'#fff'}/>
                        </RectButton>
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.menuContainer}>
                        <RectButton style={styles.menuButton} onPress={() => navigation.toggleDrawer()}>
                            <Feather name='menu' size={20} color={'#fff'}/>
                        </RectButton>
                    </View>
                </View>
                :
                <View style={styles.containerSkeleton}>
                    <ActivityIndicator size={50} color="#15c3d6"/>
                </View>}
        </View>
    );
}
```

Edit:
I've inserted the React.Component and the error stopped but still doesn't show on the map.

```
{floods.map(flood => {
                            // noinspection BadExpressionStatementJS
                            <React.Component key={flood.id}>
                            <Circle
                                center={{
                                    latitude: flood.latitude,
                                    longitude: flood.longitude,
                                }}
                                radius={Number(flood.range)}
                                fillColor={'rgba(53, 159, 181,0.4)'}
                            />
                            <Marker
                                icon={mapMarker}
                                calloutAnchor={{
                                    x: 2.7,
                                    y: 0.8
                                }}
                                coordinate={{
                                    latitude: flood?.latitude,
                                    longitude: flood?.longitude,
                                }}
                            >
                                <Callout tooltip={true} onPress={handleNavigateToIncidentDetails}>
                                    <View style={styles.calloutContainer}>
                                        <Text style={styles.calloutText}>{flood.type}</Text>
                                    </View>
                                </Callout>
                            </Marker>
                            </React.Component>
                        })}
```

Comment: You need to wrap all the components in the map return in a single parent component, it can be a React.Fragment. `floods.map(flood => (<key={flood.id}><Circle ...> ... </Marker></>))` (the key gets added to the Fragment. see: [Keyed Fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#keyed-fragments))

Comment: Thanks! This solved the error, but i still can't insert them into the map, gonna edit my code so you can see it.

Comment: Glad it helped, but it should be `<React.Fragment key={flood.id}>...</React.Fragment>` the shorthand is `<> ... </>`

Comment: @pilchard Thank you so much! You are amazing!!!!!!

Comment: No worries, glad you got it working.